# Question regarding interaction picture

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, interactions, time-evolution

$$\newcommand{ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}$$The relation between the interaction picture and Schrödinger picture states and operators are
$$\ket{\psi(t)}_{I} = e^{iH_0t} \ket{\psi(t)}_S$$
$$\mathcal{O}_I = e^{i H_0 t} \mathcal{O}_S e^{-iH_0 t}$$
and the interaction part of the Hamiltonian evolves in time as
$$H_I  = e^{i H_0 t} H_{int} e^{-iH_0 t}$$
Now if I substitute these into the Schrödinger equation
$$i \frac{d}{dt}\ket{\psi(t)}_S = (H_0 + H_{int}) \ket{\psi(t)}_S$$
It simplifies to
$$i \frac{d}{dt}\ket{\psi(t)}_I = H_I \ket{\psi(t)}_I$$
The solution of this is given by Dyson's formula
$$\ket{\psi(t)}_I = T \textrm{exp}(-i\int_0^tH_I(t')dt') \ket{\psi(0)}_I$$
But if I start with the very first equation, then I get $\ket{\psi(0)}_I = \ket{\psi(0)}_S $. Furthermore, when I use the Schrödinger equation in the Schrödinger picture, along with the first equation I get
$$\ket{\psi(t)} _I= e^{iH_0t} e^{- i(H_0 + H_{int})t}\ket{\psi(0)}_S = e^{-iH_{int}t} \ket{\psi(0)}$$
which clearly contradicts Dyson's formula. So where is my mistake?

Comment: There's no "\ket" command unless you define it. You need to use "|" and "\rangle"

Comment: $\uparrow$ I think \lvert and \rvert are more indicated than "|".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your last line, you've implicitly used that $[H_0,H_\mathrm{int}]=0$ and also that each part of the Hamiltonian $H=H_0 +H_\mathrm{int}$ is time-independent. With these assumptions, you also have that $H_I = H_{\mathrm{int}}$ and thus

$$\mathrm T \exp -i\int\limits_0^t \mathrm dt\,H_I = \exp{-iH_\mathrm {int}t} \quad ,  $$

which shows that both of your calculations yield the same expression under the said assumptions.

Comment: In my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/660297/equation-of-motion-for-time-evolution-operator-in-the-interaction-picture) I've basically generalized OP's last equation to derive the relation between the time evolution operator in the Schrödinger and interaction picture.