# Why $U(t)A_{H}(t)|\psi_{H}\rangle = A_{I}(t)|\psi_{I}(t)\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, time-evolution

Can anyone explain why $$U(t)A_{H}(t)|\psi_{H}\rangle = A_{I}(t)|\psi_{I}(t)\rangle~?$$

This equation is on Piers Coleman's book, Introduction to Many-body physics. It is used to prove

$$
A_{H} = U^{\dagger}(t) A_{I}(t) U(t) \tag{5.99}
$$

where $U(t)$ is the time evolution operator in interaction space which is Dyson time-ordered.

It may be something hidden in plaint sight, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: $UA = UAU^{\dagger}U$ because $U$ is unitary.

Comment: Yes, you can use $UA=UAU^{\dagger}U$ to prove 5.99 from the first equation. But why do we have the first equation?

Comment: I think this relation only holds if you put $t_0=0$. Indeed, if you use [these](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/660297/equation-of-motion-for-time-evolution-operator-in-the-interaction-picture) results, you should arrive (modulo typos) at $A_H=e^{-iH_0t_0} U^\dagger_I(t,t_0) A_I U_I(t,t_0) e^{iH_0t_0}$. Note that, as usual, $A_H$ as well as $A_I$ depend on $t$ but also on $t_0$  as a parameter (via the time-evolution operators). Eq. 5.7 in the book suggests that the author puts $t_0=0$, as far as I can see...

Comment: @TobiasFünke Thanks. I have worked out and explained as the following.

Comment: You're right, I made a mistake regarding the $t_0$ stuff in the comment above. Eq. $(1)$ in the linked answer actually also assumes $t_0=0$ (where $t_0$ is the time where both pictures coincide), but can be generalized easily to account for arbitrary $t_0$. So the statement in the comment above is false, I think, and only correct (and the desired result) if you also put $t_0=0$ there. But starting from the properly generalized eq. $(1)$ of the linked answer, eq. $(5.99)$ of the book immediately follows for any choice of $t_0$. You should double check all of this, though.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @TobiasFünke

1. I have worked through the page you mentioned. It was a great answer. I learned

$U_{I}(t, t') = e^{iH_{0}t}~U_{S}(t,t')~e^{-iH_{0}t'}$

I have one comment. In your answer $t'$ is assumed to be a second observation point. The initial point of the system is at $t = 0$. But in the question, $t_{0}$ is assumed to be the initial point of the system, where you turn on your Hamiltonian.

2. I have worked out the trick in my question.

$\langle\psi_{H}|A_{H}(t)|\psi_{H}\rangle = \langle\psi_{I}(t)|A_{I}(t)|\psi_{I}(t)\rangle$

$\langle\psi_{H}|A_{H}(t)|\psi_{H}\rangle = \langle\psi_{I}(0)|U_{I}(t)^{\dagger}A_{I}(t)|\psi_{I}(t)\rangle$

Since $|\psi_{I}(0)\rangle=|\psi_{S}(0)\rangle=|\psi_{H}\rangle$

$A_{H}(t)|\psi_{H}\rangle = U_{I}(t)^{\dagger}A_{I}(t)|\psi_{I}(t)\rangle$

$U_{I}(t)A_{H}(t)|\psi_{H}\rangle = A_{I}(t)|\psi_{I}(t)\rangle$

3. Unfortunately for me equ (5.7) in Piers Coleman's book is questionable. He simply wrote

$|\psi_{I}(t)\rangle = U(t)|\psi_{I}(0)\rangle$

$U(t) = e^{iH_{0}t}e^{-iHt}$    (5.7)

Where he put $H$ as a constant. However the theme of this chapter and the goal of interaction picture is separate the time dependent part $V$ and the constant $H_{0}$. Thus $H$ is supposed to be time dependent, and should be something like a Dyson Time-ordered operator.

Best.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).